# no such file or directory, scandir errno: -4058 syscall: 'scandir'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to code a discordbot with javascript, but I keep getting following error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhk6b.png)
It keeps telling me the file doesn't exist. The following picture shows my file structure.
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3AIM.png)
I tried the command npm rebuild node-sass but I had no succes.
This is my Main.js and my blau.js if u need more information to solve the error just leave a comment and I will add it. Thank u for ur help.
[Main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQuMR.png)
[Blau.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPAUm.png)

Comment: Please, make sure to provide errors, code and other relative text information in *text* form instead of screenshots in the future. It helps to save time and it makes it more likely your question will be answered.
Just a heads-up: your question might be down-voted for not doing this.

Comment: Okey thank u. I will do that the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path is not relative to the current file, unlike `require()`. It's relative to where the node process is spawned. Use this path: `./commands/methods`.

For example, writing a script like this at `~/foo.js`:

```js
console.log(process.cwd());
```

```
~ $ node foo.js
/home/USER
~ $ cd /
/ $ node ~/foo.js
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple issue, simple fix. Relative to your **main.js** file, you have a `commands` folder, and inside is the `methods` folder. Since that folder is nested inside `commands` the appropriate relative path would be

```
'./commands/methods'
```